# What does the yellow color of CPU mean in htop?

Tags: colors, htop

if press <kbd>h</kbd> inside htop for quick help:

**CPU**

```
Blue      : Low-priority threads
Green     : Normal priority threads
Red       : Kernel threads
Turquoise : Virtualization threads
```

but yellow?

[image: IMAGE: See htop result]

Comment: ServerFault dupe: [What exactly do the colors in htop status bars mean?](http://serverfault.com/q/180711)

Comment: This depends on the htop colour theme in use (default) and the terminal color scheme.

Comment: In fairness the 'dupe' doesn't have any top level answer that addresses the 'yellow' for CPU issue.  You have to dig into the comments to get the answer below.

Comment: How can we remove the "dupe" flag? That other question doesn't mention yellow cpu.

Comment: For me this IOwait was caused from an AWS T instance running out of CPU credit but can also be caused from EBS/Disk being too slow or running out of credit too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In my case, yellow means that the CPU time is spent on virtualization (for VDS) and CPU is lost. Change your hosting provider.

Comment: That's called "steal" time. It's CPU time that is unavailable to your instance due to other people making heavy use of the CPU on the same physical machine. Upon request, a decent VPS provider may move your instance to a host with less CPU contention; I know mine (Linode) would.

Answer (score 5):

Making an educated guess: you've got htop's detailed CPU time display on. Under the Black Night colorscheme, yellow is io-wait. Which makes sense for a database server.

Comment: Yes, my VPS provider had bad SSD or something else. I've changed him. Yellow meant io-wait, you are correct.